# Tensor product decomposition of V and g 

Tags: tensor-products, rt.representation-theory

Let $g$ be a simple complex Lie algebra with an irreducible representation $g\subset so(V)$ with the highest weight $\Lambda$.

In the book by Onishchik and Vinberg "Lie groups and algebraic
groups" the following formula is given. If $V_\Lambda$ and $V_M$
are irreducible $g$-modules with the highest weights $\Lambda$ and
$M$, then the multiplicity of $V_N$ in $V_\Lambda\otimes V_M$
equals

$\dim$ { $v\in(V_M)_{N-\Lambda}|(e_i)^{\Lambda_i+1}v=0, i=1,...,l$}

$=
\dim$ {$v\in(V_N)_{\Lambda-M'}|(e_i)^{M'_i+1}v=0, i=1,...,l$},

where $l$ is the rank of $g$, $\{e_i,f_i,H_i\}$ are canonical
generators of $g$, $\Lambda_i$ are labels on the Dynkin diagram,
and $M'$ is the highest weight of $(V_M)^*$, $(V_M)_{N-\Lambda}$
denotes the weight space of weight $N-\Lambda$.

Taking $V_M=g$, we obtain $$V\otimes g=kV\oplus\oplus_\lambda
V_\lambda,$$ where $k$ is the number of non-zero labels on the
Dynkin diagram of $g$ defining the representation $g\subset
so(V)$, and $V_\lambda$ are irreducible modules different from $V$
with the the highest weights $\lambda$ that are pairwise
different. Of course, one of the modules $V_\lambda$ is
$V_{\Lambda+\delta}$, $\delta$ is the highest root.

Are there some other formulas that may give more information about
$V_\lambda$? I would like to have an expression for an element
(not necessary of the highest vector) of each $V_\lambda$. Is it
possible that $V_\lambda$ contains an element of the form
$v\otimes A$, where $v\in V$, $A\in g$?

I am classifying irreducible subalgebras $g\subset so(V)$ that
admit linear maps from $V$ to $g$ satisfying some equation. I
guess that only $V_{\Lambda+\delta}$ may consist of such maps. To
show that other $V_\lambda$ do not consist of such maps, I need to
take some element from these modules and to check the equation.

The above formulas show that to each $V_\lambda$ there is a
preferred root space in $g$ of weight $\lambda-\Lambda$ and a line
in $V_\Lambda$ of weight $\lambda-\delta$. How the elements from
these lines can be used?

Comment: The set-up here looks confusing.   Is `$V$` tensored with the adjoint representation?   (The latter is irreducible only if the Lie algebra is simple.)   Other parts of the question are also unclear to me, with a serious misprint at the end, an undefined symbol `$\delta$`, etc.   And what is the decomposition method used here for the tensor product?

Answer (score 2):

I think the formula you are looking for is $V(\mu)\otimes g\cong kV(\mu) \oplus \oplus_\alpha V(\mu+\alpha)$ where the sum is over roots $\alpha$ such that $\mu+\alpha$ is a dominant weight. Here $V(\lambda)$ is irreducible with highest weight $\lambda$ for $\lambda$ an integral dominant weight.

Comment: There is a misprint: LHS should be $V(\mu)\otimes g$. Also the formula seems to fail for $\mu =0$.

Comment: I have corrected the misprint. Thanks.

Comment: For $\mu=0$, we have $k=0$, and the sum has only one term, namely $\alpha$ is the highest root.

Comment: If $g$ is not simply laced you will have two summands, is not it?

Comment: @Victor. Yes, you are right. This formula is only for the simply laced case when the Weyl group acts transitively on the roots.

Comment: Thanks! Where the formula can be found?